# xmonad vertical resize tile/window

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad

I have a few vertically stacked tiles on the left, and some on the right. I can easily horizontally resize the master pane (with **mod + l** and **mod + h**), but I'd like to *vertically* resize some windows (including non-master) in this setup.

How do I do this??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the standard XMonad `Tall` layout, but alternative layouts such as [`ResizableTall`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-ResizableTile.html) from `xmonad-contrib` support resizing the master pane.

To resize the master pane when using the `ResizableTall` layout, bind the `XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile (MirrorShrink, MirrorExpand)` messages.

For example, in [my config](https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/ca8708958bd068d31e64026e6073835729bb7763/dot.xmonad/xmonad.hs) I define my `layoutHook` and `keys` to use `ResizableTall` with two master panes, and with `Mod-M` + arrow keys bound to resizing the master panes, using (simplified)

```
main = xmonad gnomeConfig
  { layoutHook = Full ||| tall ||| Mirror tall
  , keys = myKeys
  }
  where
  -- Two master panes, 1/10th resize increment, only show master
  -- panes by default. Unlike plain 'Tall', this also allows
  -- resizing the master panes, via the 'MirrorShrink' and
  -- 'MirrorExpand' messages.
  tall = ResizableTall 2 (1/10) 1 []
  -- Add bindings for arrow keys that resize master panes.
  myKeys x = M.fromList (newKeys x) `M.union` keys gnomeConfig x
  newKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) =
    [ ((modm, xK_Left),  sendMessage MirrorExpand)
    , ((modm, xK_Up),    sendMessage MirrorExpand)
    , ((modm, xK_Right), sendMessage MirrorShrink)
    , ((modm, xK_Down),  sendMessage MirrorShrink)
    ]
```

Comment: Can confirm that [`ResizableTall`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-ResizableTile.html) works for vertical resizing.